# Quel futur doit-on utiliser quand on offre de faire quelque chose ?

Tags: futur-simple, futur, futur-proche

On suppose que Marie dit :

> La pelouse doit être tondue.

Considérons les deux réponses possibles de son mari Jacques:

> Moi, je le ferai.
>
> Moi, je vais le faire.

Est-ce que ces réponses sont différentes  ? 
En anglais,

> I'll do it.
>
> I'm going to do it.

sont très différentes entre elles. Dans la première réponse, Jacques s'engage à le faire. Dans la deuxième, Jacques informe Marie qu'il a déjà décidé de le faire (plus tard) : il annonce qu'il va le faire, il ne s'agit pas d'une offre. Cette différence existe-t-elle aussi en français ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

À mon avis [aussi](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13295) on préfère clairement « *je vais le faire* » ici, même si le contexte présenté est trop [*réduit*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13297) pour vraiment permettre d'illustrer une différence. Un complément avec un exemple où l'on n'a pas vraiment le choix:

> [...]En somme, la nuance entre les deux formes réside dans le lien
>   entre l'action future et le moment de parole, et non dans la distance
>   plus ou moins grande qui sépare l’action évoquée et le présent. Bien
>   qu’il soit possible d'employer ces deux formes pour parler d'un fait à
>   venir, on ne peut pas nécessairement les utiliser indifféremment dans
>   tous les contextes. Ainsi, lorsque l'action évoquée est située dans un
>   futur immédiat et qu'elle est vraiment ancrée dans le moment présent,
>   seul le futur proche peut être utilisé.
>
> [...]
>
> - *Je vais acheter le journal. As-tu besoin de quelque chose?* (et non : *J'achèterai le journal*.)
>
> [ *Banque de dépannage linguistique (BDL)* - [Futur proche](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4122) (voir aussi [Futur simple](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4127)) ]

Il y a des différences entre les futurs, mais il s'agit d'une [forme](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/13301/3177) d'affirmation sur ce qu'on s'apprête à faire assez immédiatement ou sur ce qu'on fera à un moment distinct. Quand on dit qu'il faudrait tondre la pelouse, il s'agit de quelque chose qu'on fait assez fréquemment et on n'en discuterait pas si le besoin n'était pas orienté vers le présent. Si quelqu'un exprime un besoin et qu'une autre personne propose d'accomplir la tâche indiquée, ça ne se traduit pas par le type de futur; c'est si l'action est connectée au moment de parole ou non qui détermine le futur approprié. En effet, on peut facilement affirmer vouloir faire quelque chose beaucoup plus tard, et le futur simple devient alors plus usuel je crois:

> A: Dans 6 mois, il faudra changer ce réservoir que tu as devant toi...
>   B: Je le ferai/changerai.
>   B1: (Je ne bouge plus jusqu'au moment opportun où) je vais le changer.(!)

Answer (score 3):

Dans le langage quotidien, le futur simple: "je le ferai" est moins utilisé que le futur proche ou immédiat: "Je vais le faire".

Dans un contexte aussi réduit, le sens reste le même.

Le futur proche indique qu'une action sera faite à court terme.

Ex: "Il fait frais. Je vais fermer les fenêtres".

"Il est midi. Je vais déjeuner".

Le futur simple indique que l'action se fera à un moment donné dans le futur. Il est même possible qu'elle ne se fasse pas.

Ex: "Je fermerai les fenêtres, si nécessaire".

"Je déjeunerai quand il y aura moins de clients dans la boutique".

Answer (score 2):

*Je vais le faire* est pour moi la formule de loin la plus idiomatique, à moins que ce ne soit explicitement dans un futur assez éloigné. On pourrait même utiliser le présent: *Je m'en occupe* serait possible.

Answer (score 2):

You use the word “offre”/offer in your question, but in your example (between spouses), I see the exchange more as a “request/order” followed by a positive “response/acquiescence” thereto than one of a “solicitation of an offer” followed by an “offer.”
With this interpretation of your example in mind, I would agree with the other answers that “Moi, je vais le faire” would be the most idiomatic and appropriate form to use.

However, in an arm’s length transaction, where an offer has to be accepted to seal the deal, I think that “Moi, je vais le faire” would be at best a bit presumptuous on the part of the maker of the “offer” in response to a real solicitation for offers.

Of the two choices, I think a lawn service technician, for example, would say, regardless of how soon s/he would begin the work, “Moi, je le ferai [pour $75.00 si vous êtes d’accord]” more often than “Moi, je vais le faire [pour $75.00 si vous êtes d’accord ou pas]” to avoid sounding too presumptuous.

Even between the related parties in your example, Marie might have a very legitimate reason for not wanting to accept Jacques’ offer (perhaps he mowed her prized Tulips the last time he did it and she’s still skeptical, for example), and in that case “Moi, je le ferai [si tu veux, ma Chérie]” would seem to be a bit less presumptuous than “Moi, je vais le faire [si t’es d’accord ou pas]” and be closer to a “real” offer (i.e., one that can be either accepted or refused).

Regardless of the validity of the possible “presumptuous” nuance that I see between the two choices, I would personally find another way to make a real offer and I’d avoid the use of the future altogether (simple ou proche) of “faire.”

Using “pouvoir” would work, I think, to put less pressure on Marie to accept Jacques’ offer: “Je peux le faire [si tu veux].” or even “Puis-je t'aider ?”

The use of the imperfect tense of “faire” -- "Et si je le faisais?" -- would be another way to suggest an offer (or at least to offer a suggestion) and avoid a possible repeat of the "tulip incident."

Answer (score 0):

Très pratiquement il y a une différence entre "je vais le faire", qui indique un engagement à court terme et "je le ferai"; ce futur comme expliqué plus haut implique une notion d'éloignement dans le temps, ce qui peut très bien faire comprendre qu'il n'est pas près de le faire...